# ubuntu - Git add - зависает терминал

Tags: ubuntu, git

Установил git.

`git status` работает, но терминал перестает реагировать при команде `git add .`

Пробовал перезагрузку, переустановку и `sudo apt-get update`.

В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод вот этой команды: `mkdir /tmp/test && cd /tmp/test && git init && touch file && git add file && git status`.

Answer (score 2):

Уже разобрался. Видимо при установке пакетов файл репозитория был поврежден. Установил в другую папку - стало ок. Спасибо.